# JQuery .load() not adding to DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using the `.load()` function in jQuery to load HTML contents stored in a separate file:

```
$('#div-id').load('contents.html');
```

And later I am trying to add a class to an element that was loaded from above:

```
$('#elements_in_contents_html').addClass('active');     // not working
```

The above has no effect on elements added from `contents.html`.

Is it because `.load()` does not add the loaded contents to the DOM tree?

Comment: Add a callback to your code to see if the function is run properly.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: It **is** adding to the DOM Tree and that's why you are able to see it. Try `$('#div-id #elements_in_contents_html').addClass('active');`?

Comment: Very good point! Nice shortcut, I tried but didn't work.

Comment: it is because ajax is asynchronous...can't update the elements before they arrive from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add it in the `callback`, so that it waits for `.load()` to get complete and then execute the `callback`:

```
$('#div-id').load('contents.html', function () {
  $('#elements_in_contents_html').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$("#myDiv").load( "/somecontroller/someaction", {data: value}, function() {
    $("#myDiv").find( "table tbody tr:even" ).addClass( "alt" );
});
```

This waits until the content has finished loading and then executes your function that attempts to operate on the content.